# in java SWT Composite do not lay out according to the set layout

Tags: java, swt

I am expecting to show two composite in the main composite when run the below code.

But it does not show child composites in it unless set the bounds for them.
But I am expecting to setBound automatically since I have applied layout.
Can some one tell me what is wrong here.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    composite.setBounds(0,0,500,500);
    RowLayout rowLayout = new RowLayout();
    rowLayout.type =SWT.VERTICAL;
    rowLayout.fill = true;
    composite.setLayout(rowLayout);

    //
    //
    Composite comB1 = new Composite(composite, SWT.BORDER);

    RowLayout comB1Layout = new RowLayout();
    comB1Layout.type =SWT.HORIZONTAL;
    comB1.setVisible(true);
    //
    //
    Composite comB2 = new Composite(composite, SWT.BORDER);

    RowLayout comB2Layout = new RowLayout();
    comB2Layout.type =SWT.HORIZONTAL;
    comB1.setVisible(true);
    shell.open();


    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a layout on the `Shell` to tell it what to do with the children.

However this will override the `setBounds` on the `Composite`. It is difficult to mix layouts with `setBounds`. Instead call `setSize` on the `Shell`.

So something like:

```
shell.setSize(500, 800);

shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);

RowLayout rowLayout = new RowLayout();
rowLayout.type =SWT.VERTICAL;
rowLayout.fill = true;
composite.setLayout(rowLayout);

Composite comB1 = new Composite(composite, SWT.BORDER);

RowLayout comB1Layout = new RowLayout();
comB1Layout.type =SWT.HORIZONTAL;
comB1.setLayout(comB1Layout);

Composite comB2 = new Composite(composite, SWT.BORDER);

RowLayout comB2Layout = new RowLayout();
comB2Layout.type =SWT.HORIZONTAL;
comB2.setLayout(comB2Layout);
```